# Haskell 99 Problems #7: Prepend vs Append to List

Tags: list, haskell

This passes:

```
data Nested List a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]
flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Elem a) = [a]
flatten (List (x:xs)) = flatten x ++ flatten (List xs)
flatten (List []) = []
```

This fails:

```
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]
flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Elem a) = [a]
flatten (List (x:xs)) = flatten x : flatten (List xs)
flatten (List []) = []
```

Error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[a]'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
      at 007.hs:2:12
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: [NestedList a] (bound at 007.hs:4:18)
  x :: NestedList a (bound at 007.hs:4:16)
  flatten :: NestedList a -> [a] (bound at 007.hs:3:1)
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `flatten x'
In the expression: flatten x : flatten (List xs)
```

The difference is `++` instead of `:`. I know the former appends, the latter prepends, but why doesn't `:` work in this case? I don't understand the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually [`++`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) is the concatenation operator, which expects both the operators to be a list in this particular case. Since `flatten` returns a list, `++` concatenates them happily.

But, `:` just prepends only one item to a list. Since `flatten x` in `flatten x : flatten (List xs)` returns a list, `:` throws this error.

Comment: Ah, I did not even think to make that distinction. Thank you!